terminal keep stopping after keyboard interrupt in python scapy script
I am starting in Wi-Fi domain and wanted to automate the packet sending process that i used. I have this main script which will ask the user to select the scenario and start sending packets and 2 other scripts one collects logs and another to run sniffer. i crated the first script so that while running, it will open two new terminals and start running the other two scripts.
The issue that am facing right now is that i have added code so that a user interrupt or keyboard interrupt happens the script will ask the user to run the code again or not, when this happens my other two terminals are getting closed. I don't know why when i run the code for the first time there was no issue it asked to run again and other two terminals stayed open. Need help in debugging the issue and if possible to optimize with reliable code format.
I have to run this code in 3 terminal because i am sending packets in an infinite loop and if possible i need to make it run all this in one terminal.
when running sniffer the terminal goes in to an interactive mode so the rest of the code was not executing that's why i wrote 3 scripts individually. This script is run in Linux environment mainly Ubuntu 20 and using network adaptor. Thanks in advance.
Main code:
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.dot11 import RadioTap, Dot11, Dot11Beacon, Dot11Elt
import re
import os
import time
import subprocess
dongle = subprocess.Popen("ifconfig", stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
output = dongle.read().decode()


def dongle_name(config_value):
    dongles = []
    for value in config_value.splitlines():
        name_of_dongle = re.search(r"wlx\w+", value)
        if name_of_dongle:
            dongles.append(name_of_dongle.group(0))
    return dongles


sniffer_dongle = dongle_name(output)
dongle_1 = sniffer_dongle[0]


subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "--", "python3", "-c", "from fuzz_2_dongle import get_dongle_and_run; get_dongle_and_run"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
time.sleep(5)
subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "--", "python3", "-c", "from log_collector import logs; logs"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout


stmt = """

------Fuzz Testing scenarios------

Scenario_1 : Create a beacon with SSID length is >32 and inject the frame in different DUT states.

"""

print(stmt)


commands = {

   'scenario_1': RadioTap()/Dot11(addr1="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",addr2=RandMAC(),addr3=RandMAC())/ Dot11Beacon(cap="ESS")/ Dot11Elt(ID="SSID",info="malformed-SSID-WithSSIDgreatedthan32")/ Dot11Elt(ID="Rates",info =' \x84\x8b\x96\x0c\x12\x18'),

}


def call_commands(command, interface):
    sendp(command, iface=interface, inter=0.1, loop=1)


def run_command():
    global dongle_1
    interface_to_run = dongle_1
    case_name = input("Please specify which scenario to run eg = 'scenario_1' : \n").lower()
    call_commands(commands[case_name], interface_to_run)


settings = True
while settings:
    run_command()
    if KeyboardInterrupt:
        user_input = input("Do you want to run the script again? (y/n): ").lower()
        if user_input == 'y':
            os.system('clear')
            print(stmt)
        elif user_input == 'n':
            settings = False


Log collector:
import subprocess
import os

log_folder = "logs"


def device():
    """gets dsn from of the attached device"""
    adb_value = subprocess.run("adb devices", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).stdout
    decoded = adb_value.decode().split('\n')[1:]
    for x in decoded:
        try:
            dsn = x.split()[0]
            print("Device detected:", dsn)
            return dsn
        except:
            print(x)
    return None  # Handle no devices found


dsn_list = device()
if dsn_list:
    print(dsn_list)
else:
    print("No devices found.")
    exit()  # Exit if no devices


def log_collector():
    """collect logs"""
    def log_loop():
        log_name = input("Enter log name: ")
        log_path = f"{log_folder}/{log_name}.txt"
        log_process = subprocess.Popen(f"adb -s {dsn_list} logcat -v time -b all > {log_path}", shell=True)
        input("Press enter to stop logging and save.")
        log_process.terminate()  # Terminate and wait implicitly
        print(f"Logs saved to {log_path}.")

    collect_again = True

    while collect_again:
        if not os.path.exists(log_folder):
            os.makedirs(log_folder)

        user_input = input("Please enter to collect log from device (Y/N): ").lower()

        if user_input == "y":
            while True:
                log_loop()
                again = input("Do you wish to collect logs again (Y/N)? ").lower()
                if again not in ("y", "n"):
                    print("Invalid input. Please enter Y or N.")
                    continue
                elif again == "n":
                    collect_again = False
                    break

        elif user_input == "n":
            collect_again = False

        else:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter Y or N.")


logs = log_collector()

sniffer:
import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import time
import re

dongle = subprocess.Popen("ifconfig", stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
output = dongle.read().decode()


def dongle_name(config_value):
    """to get the name of the sniffer dongle"""
    dongles = []
    for value in config_value.splitlines():
        name = re.search(r"wlx\w+", value)
        if name:
            dongles.append(name.group(0))
    return dongles


def setup_dongle(dongle_dsn, channel, bw):
    """runs the sniffer by getting dongle name from ifconfig channel , bandwidth from user"""
    try:
        results = subprocess.run(["sudo", "ip", "link", "set", dongle_dsn, "down"])
        if results.returncode != 0:
            return f"Failed to set dongle {dongle_dsn} down"
        time.sleep(5)
        results = subprocess.run(["sudo", "iw", dongle_dsn, "set", "monitor", "control"])
        if results.returncode != 0:
            return f"Failed to set monitor mode in dongle {dongle_dsn}"
        time.sleep(5)
        results = subprocess.run(["sudo", "ip", "link", "set", dongle_dsn, "up"])
        if results.returncode != 0:
            return f"Failed to set dongle {dongle_dsn} up"
        time.sleep(5)
        results = subprocess.run(["sudo", "iw", "dev", dongle_dsn, "set", "channel", str(channel), str(bw)])
        if results.returncode != 0:
            return f"Failed to set channel and bandwidth {dongle_dsn}"
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)


sniffer_dongle = dongle_name(output)

if not sniffer_dongle:
    print("No wlx interfaces found!")
    exit(1)

dongle_1 = sniffer_dongle[0]
print("dongle 1:", dongle_1)

dongle_2 = sniffer_dongle[1] if len(sniffer_dongle) > 1 else None
if dongle_2:
    print("dongle 2:", dongle_2)


def run_sniffer(dongle_dsn_1, dongle_dsn_2):
    """runs wireshark using 2 dongles"""
    results = subprocess.run(["sudo", "wireshark", "-i", dongle_dsn_2, "-k", "-S", "-l"])
    if results.returncode != 0:
        return "Failed to start Wireshark"
    time.sleep(5)
    return "Sniffer started successfully"


channel_1 = input("specify channel to sent packets 2G/5G : ")
channel_2 = input("enter channel to sniff 2G/5G :  ")
processes = []
for dongle_dsn, channel, bw in [(dongle_1, channel_1, "HT20"), (dongle_2, channel_2, "HT20")]:
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=setup_dongle, args=(dongle_dsn, channel, bw))
    processes.append(process)
    process.start()


for process in processes:
    process.join()

get_dongle_and_run = run_sniffer(dongle_1, dongle_2)

When running the code i don't want my log collector terminal and sniffer terminal to close when i initiate a keyboard interrupt. Those to terminal should stay open until i stop the code from  running.
